# Can I send files using ObjectMessage with Spring JMS?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I use Spring Boot, jms and IBM MQ. I know that BytesMessage exists for sending files, but using ObjectMessage would be much more convenient for me. Can I do it or this will lead to a large overhead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `JmsTemplate.convertAndSend`, Spring will automatically use the message type based on what you sent. See the `SimpleMessageConverter` (which is the default).

```java
    @Override
    public Message toMessage(Object object, Session session) throws JMSException, MessageConversionException {
        if (object instanceof Message) {
            return (Message) object;
        }
        else if (object instanceof String) {
            return createMessageForString((String) object, session);
        }
        else if (object instanceof byte[]) {
            return createMessageForByteArray((byte[]) object, session);
        }
        else if (object instanceof Map) {
            return createMessageForMap((Map<? ,?>) object, session);
        }
        else if (object instanceof Serializable) {
            return createMessageForSerializable(((Serializable) object), session);
        }
        else {
            throw new MessageConversionException("Cannot convert object of type [" +
                    ObjectUtils.nullSafeClassName(object) + "] to JMS message. Supported message " +
                    "payloads are: String, byte array, Map<String,?>, Serializable object.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The IBM MQ documentation also says that it is possible, see [The JMS message body](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032080_.htm).

Comment: To create an `ObjectMessage` the class must implement `Serializable`.

Comment: @GaryRussell yes, it must implement Serializable, so I can't just send in MQ my MultipartFile which I get from rest. So, I have to wrap it in something serializable or convert it to bytes. Which way is preferable?

Comment: Note that there are security concerns about use of ObjectMessage. You might have to provide a whitelist file to name the classes that can be transferred that way. See [the docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q127290_.htm)

Comment: `>So, I have to wrap it in something serializable ` That won't work since all fields must be `Serializable` (or `transient` - which means skip this field) to use Java serialization. Consider using some other technique, such as JSON.